# Show Linux operating system choices

Tags: windows-7, linux-mint

I've had Linux Mint installed along with my Windows 7 partition. Recently, I reinstalled my Windows 7 partition and now the operating system choices menu that Linux Mint created no longer shows up. Is there a way to bring it back?

Comment: You have learned the hard way, that Windows installation doesn't care about *other* OS.

Comment: Well, how do I get to Mint?

Comment: Follow Ignacio's advice

Answer (score 3, accepted):

["How To Restore Grub After Windows 7 Repair Install ?"](http://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?f=46&t=55686&start=0)

Answer (score 0):

For completeness, note that you can do things in the opposite direction to what M. Vazques-Abram suggests, and [add GRUB (placed in the Linux partition) to the Microsoft Boot Manager menu](http://blogs.technet.com/b/port25/archive/2006/10/13/http-port25-technet-com-archive-2006-10-12-windows-and-linux-integration-3a00-a-conversation-with-the-author-aspx.aspx).  Essentially you simply need to:

- Ensure that GRUB/LILO/whatever is in your Linux partition, or in a dedicated partition of its own, and is not installed like a computer virus in the first few sectors of your disc.
- Tell Microsoft's Boot Manager to include a new menu option that chain loads to the VBR from that partition, to start GRUB/LILO/whatever.

Cyril Voisin gives the detailed instructions, including the exact `bcdedit` commands.